# Meteor Collection not fetching data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a tracker function that was working fine until I edited other file and made the application a bit more complex which somehow lead to this issue. The function is not returning any data for

1. `vrLoan`
2. `fundingData`

My code:

```
Tracker.autorun(()=>{ // Tracker function for reactivity
  const id = Session.get('data')._id;
  const loans = Loans.find({fileId: id});

  loans.forEach(o=>{
    const vrLoan = VRLoans.find({parentId: o._id});
    const fundingData = Funding.find({parentId: o._id});

    const t = o.Type;
    const n = o.description;

    if(t && n  && vrLoan.count() && fundingData.count()){
      console.log("here")
      fundDep.changed();
      fundingNameSpace[t] = {};

      if(t == "Bank Loan" || t == "Directors Loan" || t == "Lease" || t == "Loan Out/Invesment"){
        fundingNameSpace[t][n] = new LoanCalc(t, vrLoan, fundingData);
      }else if(t == "Share"){
        fundingNameSpace[t][n] = new ShareCapCalc(vrLoan, fundingData);
      }else if(t == "Other"){
        fundingNameSpace[t][n] = new OtherIncomeCalc(vrLoan, fundingData);
      }else if(t == "Cap"){
        fundingNameSpace[t][n] = new CapitalGrantCalc(vrLoan, fundingData);
      }
    });
  });
```

I guess that the new code I added must have slowed the query somehow because the length of queries is 0.

Can some one explain to me why this is happening?

Comment: console.log("here"); is this working ?

Comment: Are the `VRLoans` and `Funding` collections being published to the client? This won't be a case of them not being ready since the tracker will pick up changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` statement won't run because you check `vrLoans` and `fundingData` for `length`, but they are mongo cursors (objects) and not actual arrays.

So instead of `.length`, you want `.count()` to check they aren't empty (or call `.fetch()` after your `find()` to get ordinary js arrays).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.count/

(HOWEVER, because of this error it doesn't look like this function would ever have done anything, so presumably you must have modified it when you changed the rest of your app.)